# group duplicate values from array and print them php

Tags: php, arrays

I have list with categories that sometimes appear duplicate. I want to them belonging to the same category as in groups. Current output is as follows:

```
Mercedes
Vito

Mercedes
A Klasse

Opel
Corsa

Mercedes
CLA
```

I want them to print like:

```
Mercedes
Vito
A Klasse
CLA

Opel
Corsa
```

my code:

```
$string = json_decode('{"cars_array":[{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"Vito"},{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"A Klasse"},{"brand":"Opel","model":"Corsa"},{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"CLA"}]}',true);
$catArray = array();

foreach ($string['cars_array'] as $k => $product) {
    echo $product['brand']."\n";
    echo $product['model']."\n\n";
}
```

What I have tried so far:

```
$string = json_decode('{"cars_array":[{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"Vito"},{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"A Klasse"},{"brand":"Opel","model":"Corsa"},{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"CLA"}]}',true);
$catArray = array();

foreach ($string['cars_array'] as $k => $product) {

    if (array_key_exists($product['brand'], $catArray)) {
        $catArray[$product['brand']] = array('model' => $product['model'] );
    }else{
        $catArray[$product['brand']] = $product['brand'];
        $catArray[$product['brand']] = array('model' => $product['model'] );
    }
   
}

var_dump($catArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group items by using a named array, then assign values by pushing them with `[]` syntax

```
$string = json_decode('{"cars_array":[{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"Vito"},{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"A Klasse"},{"brand":"Opel","model":"Corsa"},{"brand":"Mercedes","model":"CLA"}]}',true);
$catArray = array();

foreach ($string['cars_array'] as $k => $product) {

    // create an array grouped on brand’s value
    $catArray[$product['brand']][] = $product['model'];

    echo $product['brand']."\n";
    echo $product['model']."\n\n";
}

foreach($catArray as $brand => $modelList) {
    print "$brand\n";
    foreach($modelList as $model) {
        print "$model\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try to use array unique in $string

```
$string_arr = array_unique($string);
```

then Implode it
$echo_arr = implode($string_arr)
echo $echo_arr;

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it